# How to set npm run dev as starter for your app?

Tags: javascript, npm

I am working with React and I am trying to figure out how to set `npm run dev` in order to compile and put my app to work. Right now, I need to do this in the terminal in order to see my app running

> $ node server/index.js

here is the way I have my folders

[image]

and here is what I have in `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "iOS.server2x.socket",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "iOS Live Socket.",
  "author": "iOS Interactive",
  "main": "server/index.js",
  "port": 1101,
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "eslint ./server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 0",
    "start": "rm -rf /home/git/.forever/chat.log; forever start --uid 'chat' ./server/index.js",
    "stop": "forever stop chat"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "xxxxxx",
    "url": "http://url/url"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^1.4.2",
    "babel": "5.8.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "4.0.5",
  }
}
```

And also, should I need webpack for this ?

Answer (score 3):

I will answer my own question:

there is a way to set this actually, all I did is in the package.json in the scripts part

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./server/index.js",
    "pretest": "eslint ./server",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 0",
    "start": "rm -rf /home/git/.forever/chat.log; forever start --uid 'chat' ./server/index.js",
    "stop": "forever stop chat"
  }
```

so, `npm run <here something in that json>`, like

`$ npm run dev` in order to start the server

`$ npm run pretest` this is the task to run `eslint`

and so on . . .